# Save before initial save of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a `conversation` is created, I want that conversation to have its `creator` automatically following it:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :followers
    has_many :users, through: :followers

    alias_method :user, :creator

    before_create { add_follower(self.creator) }

    def add_follower(user)

        unless self.followers.exists?(user_id: user.id)
            self.transaction do
                self.update_attributes(follower_count: follower_count + 1)
                self.followers.create(user_id: user.id)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

However, when a user attempts to create a conversation I get a `stack level too deep`
. I'm creating an infinite loop, and I think this is because the `before_create` callback is being triggered by the `self.update_attributes` call.

So how should I efficiently update attributes before creation to stop this loop happening?

Comment: @Mischa That stops the loop! Thanks. However, doesn't this mean the instance is being saved, retrieved, edited and saved again? Is it possible to just do it in memory before its initially created? Just feels that would be a tad more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 (preferred)

Rename your column `follower_count` to `followers_count` and add:

```
class Follower
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  # you can avoid renaming the column with "counter_cache: :follower_count"
  # rest of your code
end
```

Rails will handle updating `followers_count` for you.

Then change your add_follower method to:

```
def add_follower(user)
  return if followers.exists?(user_id: user.id)
  followers.build(user_id: user.id)
end
```

### Option 2

If you don't want to use counter_cache, use `update_column(:follower_count, follower_count + 1)`. `update_column` does not trigger any validations or callbacks.

### Option 3

Finally you don't need to save anything at this point, just update the values and they will be saved when callback finishes:

```
def add_follower(user)
  return if followers.exists?(user_id: user.id)
  followers.build(user_id: user.id)
  self.follower_count = follower_count + 1
end
```